# Finding when $x^3-x-1$ splits $\bmod p$ using the Dedekind eta function

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms

I'm reading this paper (Higher Reciprocity Laws and Modular Forms of Weight One by T. Hiramatsu), and I'm trying to prove the examples given at the end. Specifically: the number of solutions of $x^3 - x - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ is given by $$a(p)^2 - \left( \frac{-23}{p} \right),$$
where $(\frac{-23}{p})$ is the Legendre symbol and $a(p)$ is the $p$th coefficient of the expansion $$\eta(\tau)\eta(23\tau) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a(n)q^n, \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ q=e^{2\pi i\tau},$$ and $\eta(\tau)$ is the Dedekind eta function.

So here is what I've done. I've shown that by Euler's pentagonal number theorem
$$F(\tau) = \eta(\tau)\eta(23\tau) = \sum_{u,v \in \mathbb{Z}} (-1)^{u+v}q^{((6u+1)^2 + 23(6v+1)^2)/24}.$$
From the paper, we have that F is a modular form of type $(1,\epsilon)$ of $\Gamma_0(92)$, where
$$\epsilon(d) = \left( \frac{-23}{d} \right).$$

The Hecke operator acts on F by 
$$T_pF = F(p\tau) + \frac{1}{p}\sum_{b=0}^{p-1}F\left(\frac{\tau +b}{p}\right)$$
I don't think it should be too hard to show this is an eigenform, I probably just need to show that $a(n)$ is multiplicative and maybe some relationship between consecutive prime powers. Though, **I'm unsure as to whether the multiplicativity should follow from it being a Hecke eigenform, and that I should be proving it a different way.**

Once it is shown to be a Hecke eigenform, there is a theorem by Serre and Deligne, which says that there is a corresponding linear representation
$$\rho: \mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}) \to GL_2(\mathbb{C})$$ 
and if $p$ is a prime for which $\rho$ is unramified, then 
$$\mathrm{tr}(\rho(\text{Frob}_p)) = a(p) \quad\text{ and }\quad \det(\rho(\text{Frob}_p)) = \epsilon(p).$$
Furthermore, $\ker\rho = \mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/K)$, where $K$ is some finite Galois extension.

**My main question is this: How do I find a polynomial $f$ such that $K$ is the splitting field of $f$?** For this particular case, I know that $f(x) = x^3-x-1$ works, but I have no clue how to show this is true. My professor, sent me a link to [this](http://galoisdb.math.upb.de/home) site, and I should be able to determine which extension it is by just looking at traces, but **I'm curious as to whether there are any general methods for computing this**.

I'm able to show that $a(p) = 0 \iff \rho(\text{Frob}_p)$ is a matrix of order 2 , and by looking at conjugacy classes of $S_3$ I can determine that this corresponds to the fact that $f(x)$ factors as a linear polynomial and an irreducible quadratic over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Similarly, $f(x)$ is irreducible if $a(p) = -1$, and $f$ splits completely if $a(p) = 2$. Showing that these are the only values $a(p)$ can take shouldn't be too hard. I imagine it just involves some modular arithmetic and that fact that the theorem by Serre and Deligne gives that $|a(p)| \leq 2$.

**If I can solve all of this, the last thing I would hope to find, are conditions on $p$ for which $a(p)$ takes on the values above.** I can show that $a(p) = 0$ if $\left(\frac{-23}{p}\right)=-1$. In the paper I'm reading, in a previous example, he uses the fact that if $\left(\frac{-11}{p}\right) = 1$ then there exists $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $p = a^2 + ab + 3b^2$ to show that the coefficients of the modular form in that example are determined by whether $p = x^2 + 11y^2$ or $3p = x^2 + 11y^2$. However, that claim that $p = a^2+ab+3b^2$ relies on the fact that $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{-11}}{2}\right]$ is a UFD. In the example I'm trying to prove, the analogous case would be to use $p = a^2+ab+6b^2$ to split it into the cases of whether $p = x^2+23y^2$ or $6p = x^2 + 23y^2$, and I can do this with no problems. The main problem with this however, is that $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{-23}}{2}\right]$ has class number 3, so we don't always have that $p = a^2 + ab + 6b^2$. **My final question is how can I get around this failure of unique factorization?** One idea I have, is to instead use the class number and to show that $p^3 = a^2 + ab + 6b^2$ IS possible to possibly determine $a(p^3)$ and then use the recurrence relation for $a(p^n)$ to determine the value of $a(p)$. However, I'm completely stuck here and have no clue if this will actually work or will involve some kind of circular argument.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Uh ... is $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{-11})$ UFD?  I thought $\mathbb{Z}((1+\sqrt{-11})/2)$ was, instead.

Comment: Yea, you're right, I've edited accordingly.

Comment: http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hudson_Williams_1991.pdf